# Generating mean column calculated over a time window defined by a categorical variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, moving-average

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
structure(list(week  = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 
               freq  = c(0, 4.34, 1.24, 0, 5.26, 0, 7.12, 3.70, 0, 0), 
               event = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I need to do is to create a new column calculating, in correspondence of event=1, the average of freq for the window between -2 and -4 previous weeks, identified by the variable week.
For instance, since event=1 at week 7, I would like to average freq for weeks 2, 3, 4 and 5. This has to be repeated every time event is equal to 1. That mean value should be reported in the new column in the row where event=1.

Similarly, I will need to generate another column with the mean of window -1 ; +2 with respect to event=1, so in this case weeks 6 to 9.

The final result should look like this:

```
week    freq    event     mean1     mean2
1       0       0         NA        NA
2       4.34    0         NA        NA
...
7       7.12    1         2.71      2.705
...
```

I would be grateful if you could help me on this, I've read several similar threads but I couldn't find a solution to this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your question. Your `dput` wasn't working, so I have repaired it. Secondly, you say that you want to work out a window from -4 to -2 weeks. That would be weeks 3, 4 and 5, not weeks 2, 3, 4 and 5. For this example, I have assumed you meant -5 to -2 weeks, though this is easy to change as you will see.

The following function will allow you to specify a relative start and stop position to the window in your `frequency` column.

This function could be made a lot more concise and efficient using libraries such as `data.table`, but I have given a base R solution here and tried to write it in such a way as to make the logic easy to follow:

```r
relative_window <- function(variable, start, stop)
{
  result <- rep(NA, length(variable))
  if(start > stop | start > length(variable) | stop > length(variable)) return(result)
  start_indices <- seq_along(variable) + start
  stop_indices  <- seq_along(variable) + stop
  ss <- which(start_indices > 0 & stop_indices <= length(variable))
  start_indices <- start_indices[ss]
  stop_indices <- stop_indices[ss]
  index <- seq_along(variable)[ss]
  for(i in seq_along(ss))
  {
    result[index[i]] <- mean(variable[start_indices[i]:stop_indices[i]])
  }
  return(result)
}
```

So now you can just do:

```
df$mean1 <- ifelse(df$event == 1, relative_window(df$freq, -5, -2), NA)
df$mean2 <- ifelse(df$event == 1, relative_window(df$freq, -1, 2), NA)
```

Which gives you

```
df
#>    week freq event mean1 mean2
#> 1     1 0.00     0    NA    NA
#> 2     2 4.34     0    NA    NA
#> 3     3 1.24     0    NA    NA
#> 4     4 0.00     0    NA    NA
#> 5     5 5.26     0    NA    NA
#> 6     6 0.00     0    NA    NA
#> 7     7 7.12     1  2.71 2.705
#> 8     8 3.70     0    NA    NA
#> 9     9 0.00     0    NA    NA
#> 10   10 0.00     0    NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution assuming I have understood you correctly:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(car_weekly)
car_weekly[, mean1 := fifelse(event == 1, shift(frollmean(freq, n = 4), 2), NA_real_) ]
car_weekly[, mean2 := fifelse(event == 1, shift(frollmean(freq, n = 4), -2), NA_real_)]


   week freq event mean1 mean2
 1:    1 0.00     0    NA    NA
 2:    2 4.34     0    NA    NA
 3:    3 1.24     0    NA    NA
 4:    4 0.00     0    NA    NA
 5:    5 5.26     0    NA    NA
 6:    6 0.00     0    NA    NA
 7:    7 7.12     1  2.71 2.705
 8:    8 3.70     0    NA    NA
 9:    9 0.00     0    NA    NA
10:   10 0.00     0    NA    NA
```